# Relation as the Union of 4 Relations

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, relations

I'm trying to write the relation
$$\rho=\{\langle{x},y\rangle\in{\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}}: |x|+2|y|=1\}$$
as the union of 4 relations.  Is it enough to just think of this as a diamond and use the four sides as 4 different relations?  What I mean is
$$\alpha=\{\langle{x},y\rangle\in{\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}}: x+2y=1, 0\lt{x}\le{1},0\le{y}\lt{1/2}\}$$
$$\beta=\{\langle{x},y\rangle\in{\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}}: x-2y=1, 0\le{x}\lt{1},-1/2\le{y}\lt{0}\}$$
$$\gamma=\{\langle{x},y\rangle\in{\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}}: -x+2y=1, -1\lt{x}\le{0},0\lt{y}\le{1/2}\}$$
$$\delta=\{\langle{x},y\rangle\in{\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}}: -x-2y=1, -1\le{x}\lt{0},-1/2\le{y}\lt{0}\}$$
I've mapped it out and I think this is exactly what is asked  of me since now
$$\alpha\cup\beta\cup\gamma\cup\delta=\rho$$
This last question was homework but the next is just me being inquisitive.  How do you deform the above relation $\rho$ to make a circle?  What is the continuous function?  I know since these are both connected and continuous there are ways in topology to do this but I've not taken topology (doing set theory first) and was just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve written $\rho$ correctly as the union of four (pairwise disjoin) relations on $\Bbb R$; if there are no other conditions to be met, then you’ve done what was required.

Perhaps the easiest way to deform the set $\rho$ to a circle is to deform it to the unit circle $S^1=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R\times\Bbb R:x^2+y^2=1\}$ by expanding it radially. For each $p=\langle x,y\rangle\in\rho$ let $r_p=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, the distance from $p$ to the origin, and let $e_p=\frac1{r_p}$; then $\frac12\le r_p\le 1$, so $1\le e_p\le 2$. For each $p\in\rho$, $e_pp\in S^1$: $e_p$ is the factor be which $p$ must be expanded to move it out to $S^1$.

Now define

$$f:\rho\times[0,1]\to\Bbb R\times\Bbb R:\langle p,t\rangle\mapsto\big(1+t(e_p-1)\big)p\;;$$

then $f$ is continuous, $f(p,0)=p$ for each $p\in\rho$, and $f(p,1)=e_pp\in S^1$ for each $p\in\rho$. That is, if $X_t=\{f(p,t):p\in\rho\}$ for each $t\in[0,1]$, then as $t$ moves from $0$ to $1$, $\rho=X_0$ is deformed continuously through the sets $X_t$ with $0<t<1$ to $X_1=S^1$.